# react-beautiful-dnd / TypeScript - JSX element type 'DragDropContext' is not a constructor function for JSX elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using TypeScript with the react-beautiful-dnd library (and React of course) but I can't seem to get past this error:

> [ts] JSX element type 'DragDropContext' is not a constructor function
>   for JSX elements.   Types of property 'render' are incompatible.
>       Type '() => ReactNode' is not assignable to type '{ (): ReactNode; (): false | Element; }'.
>         Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'false | Element'.
>           Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'false | Element'.

I've looked at and copied several examples to try and figure out why this error is turning up and I'm coming up blank.

Here is my code, most of it is copied directly from the documentation as a test:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Component} from 'react';

import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';


interface Item {
    id: string,
    content: string,
  }


interface TodoListProps extends React.Props<TodoList> {

}

interface TodoListState {
    items: Item[]
}

const getItemStyle = (draggableStyle:any, isDragging: boolean): Object => ({
    // some basic styles to make the items look a bit nicer
    userSelect: 'none',
    padding: 8 * 2,

    // change background colour if dragging
    background: isDragging ? 'lightgreen' : 'grey',

    // styles we need to apply on draggables
    ...draggableStyle,

    margin: draggableStyle && draggableStyle.margin ? draggableStyle.margin : `0 0 ${8}px 0`,
  });

  const getListStyle = (isDraggingOver:boolean) => ({
    background: isDraggingOver ? 'lightblue' : 'lightgrey',
    padding: 8,
    width: 250
  });


// a little function to help us with reordering the result
const reorder = (list:any[], startIndex:number, endIndex:number) => {
    const result = Array.from(list);
    const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
    result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);

    return result;
  };


export default class TodoList extends React.Component<{},TodoListState>{

    private constructor(props:any){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: [
                {id: "0", content: 'Hello'}
            ]
        }

    }

    componentDidMount(){


    }

    onDragEnd = (result: any) => {
        // dropped outside the list
        if (!result.destination) {
          return;
        }

        const items = reorder(
          this.state.items,
          result.source.index,
          result.destination.index
        );

        this.setState({
          items
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
          <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
            <Droppable droppableId='droppable'>
              {(dropProvided, snapshot) => (
                <div
                  ref={dropProvided.innerRef}
                  style={getListStyle(snapshot.isDraggingOver)}
                >
                  {this.state.items.map(item => (
                    <Draggable key={item.id} draggableId={item.id}>
                      {(provided, snapshot) => (
                        <div>
                          <div
                            ref={provided.innerRef}
                            style={getItemStyle(
                              provided.draggableStyle,
                              snapshot.isDragging
                            )}
                            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                          >
                            {item.content}
                          </div>
                          {provided.placeholder}
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </Draggable>
                  ))}
                </div>
              )}
            </Droppable>
          </DragDropContext>
        );
    }
}
```

If I can't get past the error is there a way I can just tell TypeScript to ignore certain jsx errors?

**Update:**

I fixed the issue by deleting my lock file, my node_modules folder, and all my dependencies from my package.json. I reinstalled everything from scratch using npm again and it started working. Must have been a version mismatch somewhere.

Thank you to everyone that took the time to look and comment!

Comment: Why do you declare `TodoListProps` but not use it?

Comment: Not sure if it'll solve your issue, but the constructor on react classes should never be private. Remove the `private` keyword on the constructor of `TodoList`.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code into a typescript file and I haven't gotten any type errors. Maybe check to make sure you have all of the right `@type/*`  dependencies for your libraries (one is required for react, react-dom, and react-beautiful-dnd) and make sure they're all the latest version. For good measure, delete `node_modules` and reinstall everything.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I was using the props but in trying to get this to work I wanted to copy the documentation more and they didn't use props. Once I get it to work I will add them back.

Comment: I have all the types and I've tried deleting the lock file and the node modules folder a few times. Maybe I will just try making a new project if this one is bugged.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, so I'm just repasting your comment here so you can accept an answer:

> I fixed the issue by deleting my lock file, my node_modules folder, and all my dependencies from my package.json. I reinstalled everything from scratch using npm again and it started working. Must have been a version mismatch somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Update your **React.js** typings.

with npm:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react@latest @types/react-dom@latest
```

with yarn:

```
yarn add @types/react@latest @types/react-dom@latest --dev
```